# Как в hibernate хранить деревья ? Spring boot mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

Модель :

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private static int maxCost;
@Column(name = "task_cost")
private int cost;
// the cost of the task along the critical path
@Column(name = "task_criticalCost")
private int criticalCost;
// a name for the task for printing
@Column(name = "task_name")
private String name;
// the earliest start
@Column(name = "task_earlyStart")
private int earlyStart;
// the earliest finish
@Column(name = "task_earlyFinish")
private int earlyFinish;
// the latest start
@Column(name = "task_latestStart")
private int latestStart;
// the latest finish
@Column(name = "task_latestFinish")
private int latestFinish;



// the tasks on which this task is dependant

@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name="dependenciesTask")
private Task taskDependencies;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="taskDependencies")
private Set<Task> dependencies = new HashSet<Task>();
```

Делаю через fk маппинг ссылкой на id

@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name="dependenciesTask")
private Task taskDependencies;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="taskDependencies")
private Set dependencies = new HashSet();

Как сделать отображение в jsp , чтобы была возможность сетить taskDependencies?

Контроллер:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/addTask", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createTask(@ModelAttribute("taskForm")Task task, Model model)
{

    task.setEarlyFinish(-1);
    task.setEarlyStart(0);
    task.setCriticalCost(0);

    Iterable<Task> taskIterable = taskService.getAllTask();

    model.addAttribute("allTask", taskIterable);



    taskService.addTask(task);

    return "addTask";
}
```

Отображение :

```
    <body>
```

Create your timetable
        
            
                
                
            
        

        
            
                
                
            
        

                    
                        
                        
                    
                                Submit
                '>View allTask

```
     </body>
                    </html>
```

вопрос конкретно в этом куске :

```
<form:select path="taskDependencies">
                <form:option value="NONE" label=" -- Please Select --" />
                <form:options items="${allTask}" />
            </form:select>
```